# Weblogic not creating JNDI destination correctly

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi, wlst

I am encountering some weird behaviour upon creating destinations in a JMS ConnectionFactory. I have a script that adds the destinations using WLST. Usually this works fine, but once in a while I get the following behavior (like when I add them right after a server restart). If i remove and re-add the destinations, everything is peachy again.

Say, I have the following JNDI-names (where AAA is my application name)

```
/jms/queue/aaa/AAA.1.TargetServiceA.1.TargetEventA.Event.1
/jms/queue/aaa/AAA.1.TargetServiceB.1.TargetEventBWithAVeryVeryLongName.Event.1
```

This creates the following JNDI-tree (I've compacted the first part of the tree, since that is not where the problem is).

```
serverName/AAA/jms/queue/AAA/1/TargetServiceA/1
|- TargetEventA
|-- Event
|--- 1
|- TargetEventBWithAVeryVeryLongName
|-- Event
|-- [!] 1
```

Where the `[!]`-part is actually this little image: [image: error-icon]. I can't find any relevant messages in the serverlogs.

Since the `TargetEventBWithAVeryVeryLongName` is, in my case, 33 character long I wondered if maybe the path-element-length had any restrictions. Could there be any other reasons why weblogic (version 10.3.6) does not like this particular queue?

Comment: When you see that ! symbol, is the jms queue still available/can you use it? I don't think there is a character length restriction

Comment: The script creates the queue in TibcoEMS first and then the Weblogic destination. So it should be available. If I remove the weblogic destination and re-create it, it usually works.